# AIR Android Sound continues playing after I close the app

Tags: android, audio, air

I have a problem here that I added a Sound in my app and it plays normally, but I would like that when I close the app (return to the home screen) the sounds stop playing. The only way I can stop it now is killing the app that continued to run in background.

Is there something I can do to stop any sound that the app does?

Answer (score 1):

Do you play your music in Service? Anyway, you should stop the playing manually in onStop method.

Comment: No, it's a local sound that is playing on loop. I have found a way here, but I'm not sure if it's the best way, I expected it could have some configuration we could add in the descriptor xml. I'm listening the Event.ACTIVATE and Event.DEACTIVATE events and stopping it in the deactivate. It's working now

Answer (score 0):

call the mediaPlayer.stop() method when finish MainActivity class.

good luck to you!